# CodeMirror test whether value has changed

Tags: javascript, codemirror, textchanged

This question has a JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/redmeat/L6p85fjc](https://jsfiddle.net/redmeat/L6p85fjc).

I'm attempting to make a server call when [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) loses focus, but I first want to check if the value has changed.

CodeMirror provides [an API](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api) for testing whether a value has changed, including whether the value was undone:

- `doc.changeGeneration(?closeEvent: boolean) → integer`
- `doc.isClean(?generation: integer) → boolean`

From the documentation: *`changeGeneration` returns a number that can later be passed to `isClean` to test whether any edits were made (**and not undone**) in the meantime.*

However if changes are reverted using the backspace or delete keys rather than undo and redo shortcuts, the form is considered not clean even if a change generation number is provided to `isClean` and the value is back where it started.

[This JSFidlde](https://jsfiddle.net/redmeat/L6p85fjc/72/) shows that the values can match, but unless undo or redo shortcuts (`ctrl+z` and `ctrl+y`) are used, the form is considered dirty.

1. Open [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/redmeat/L6p85fjc/74/).
2. Add a character to the end of `foo`.

Next, either:

- Use the backspace key to remove the character.
- OR
- Use the `Ctrl+z` shortcut to remove the character.

In both scenarios the final value is the same as the original value. But it is only in the second scenario where `isClean` is true.

**Question:** Is there any way to check if the value is **different**? I naively expected `isClean` + `changeGeneration` to help here :/